# JQuery request XML from FTP

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, ftp

Can I use JQuery to download a XML file on a FTP server?
I want to parse the file size from the XML. Use 2754 as example value.

```
function getPDBEFileSizeByID(pdbeID) {
    pdbeID = '2754';
    var url = "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/emdb/structures/EMD-" + pdbeID + "/header/emd-" + pdbeID + ".xml";

    var request = $.get(url);

    request.done(function(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response);

        $fileSpecs = $(xmlDoc).find('*/map/file');
        var sizeKB = $fileSpecs.attr('sizeKb');

    });
}
```

Right now I am getting a CORS error. I know what it is of course, but not sure if that's an effect of JQuery or FTP.

EDIT:
CORS is only available for HTTP, ok. I must integrate that on the serverside then...

Comment: On which web browser did you tried that.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is only available for HTTP, ok. I must integrate that on the serverside then...

Comment: I would cURL the ftp and print it so it goes trough HTTP.
It can be as simple as `echo file_get_contents($_GET['URL']);`

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I am storing the file for later purposes now. Cheers!

Comment: @ElDude : not that stupid. If you client side script is hosted on the ꜰᴛᴘ server, it will works.